# Create node if it does not exist, otherwise append the returned html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, comments, nodes

I am building comment system with one level deep nested reply. My comment system is base on `<ul>` and `<li>` markups. Below is the tree example:

```html
<ul class="comments">
  <li>comment text 1</li>
  <li>
    comment text 2
    <ul class="nested">
      <li>Reply 1 of comment text 2</li>
      <li>Reply 2 of comment text 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment is Ajax base (jQuery). My question is how to check if nested reply exists for a parent level comment? If it exist then I should be able to just append the new comment, if not then I should be able to create the child `<ul class="nested">` node and then insert the returned html.

So taking the above example, If someone is replying to `comment text 1`, I should be able to create `<ul>` node first and then insert the returned `<li>` element. But if someone is replying to  `comment text 2`. I should be able to append the returned `<li>` elements into the existing `<ul>` child node.

`

Answer (score 0):

We can check the existence of a child ".nested" by getting its length .
If $(this) is your list Item li tag(comment text 1)...

```
<script>

    var comment = 'Reply 1 of comment text 1';
    if($(this).find('.nested').length > 0) {
        $(this).find('.nested').append('<li>'+comment+'</li>');
    } else {
        $(this).append('<ul class="nested"><li>'+comment+'</li></ul>');
    }

</script>
```